# Conversion -- any negative implications if grandfather was a kohen?

Tags: gentiles, conversion-to-judaism, kohen-priest, children

Someone coming from a Jewish family but not halakhically Jewish (e.g., with a Jewish maternal grandfather but not grandmother) is converting through an an Orthodox conversion. That person then discovers her maternal grandfather's last name meant he was probably a Kohen.

Are there implications for the children or grandchildren of that person since children of Kohanim who married 'forbidden' women can be chalal? On the other side I heard conversion is like being reborn and family history doesn't apply.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3886/a-beginner-s-guide-to-my-how-is-this-site-different-from-other-judaism-sites) Madelyn. Please consider [registering](//judaism.stackexchange.com/users/signup-unregistered) your account, to [enable](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) more site features, including voting.

Comment: Since this site is not for personal questions, I allowed myself to edit yours to make it more general. If you disagree or wish to edit further, please do so using the [edit](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/87726/edit) button

Comment: You should also consider taking the [Tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) if not already done

Comment: What exactly is your question? Whether converts descendants of Kohanim have the same status as Kohanim?

Comment: A similar question could be asked (and I think it has on this site) about someone who converts and has a Jewish father but a non-Jewish mother. Are they ben Avraham Avinu or ben [insert their Jewish father's name]? The answer is that they're ben Avraham. The same goes for a family who converts. The parents and children both convert, but they're all bnei Avraham veSarah, even the children whose parents converted and adopted Jewish names.

Comment: I should point out that the name of the Jewish grandfather is not evidence that he was a kohen. My shul had three families named Cohen. One is a Kohen, one is a Levi, and one is a Yisrael. You would need to get better evidence. In any case you should change the question to be more general such as `What if the person wanting to convert discovers that one of the grandfathers was a kohen who had a child with a nonJewish woman, would the convert be a *chalal* once he or she becomes Jewish?`

Answer (score 3):

A "chalal" would be the Jewish product of a Kohen and someone a Kohen can't marry, such as a divorcee or a convert.

If someone is not Jewish, however, there is no room for any other halachic category on them; if they convert, the only halachic category they bear is "convert." (Well okay they could be "Edomite" convert or "Ammonite" convert, but we don't find those today.)

So if a kohen marries a definitely-non-Jewish woman, their children are just plain "not Jewish"; if they convert, they're just plain "converts"; there's no room here for the status of "chalal."

(Starting point for this is the last Mishna of Kiddushin Ch. 3 -- if a *mamzer* marries a non-Jewish woman, the children are just plain "not Jewish"; there's no room for the category of "Mamzer.")